# How to retrieve the values from an form to another html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

My code is ...

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="GET">      
    <input type="text" name="StuserID" id="basic" value=""  placeholder="userID"   /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
```

So, when I pressed the Login it will call method validateForm() and returns the boolean

```
 function validateForm()        
     {  
         var x=document.forms["myForm"]["StuserID"].value;  
            if (x==null || x=="")  
      {  
         alert("Name must be filled out");  
          return false;  
      }
    }
```

Firstly, if the userId is null it should show an alert "Name must be filled out" and return false. In my case, it is succeeding and move to demo_form.html. How can I make it so that form submission and continuing to demo_form.html is only done when function returns true?

Secondly, how do I get the userid in demo_form.html from the form when pressing the login button?

Comment: You can't post value to demo_form.html page because its HTML. Use php demo_form.php

Comment: It is used in jquery mobile ,so  no other server side code as php or cf is supported. thn how i passed to an html?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Checkout [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LE5z/)

Comment: @Shreshtt Bhatt.. I also gone through tat.. bt in my case if  function returns false..moves to demo_form.html

Answer (score 3):

you have to use php file to retrieve data from html form.your html code form should be

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="GET">      
<input type="text" name="StuserID" id="basic" value=""  placeholder="userID"  required /> 
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
```

and then

```
function validateForm()        
         {  
             var x=document.getElementById["StuserID"].value;  
                if (x=="")  
          {  
             alert("Name must be filled out");  
              return false;  
          }
                else 
          {
                return true;
          }
        }
```

your should use following code for demo_form.php file

```
<?php
$user = $_GET['StuserID'];
echo $user;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Because `false` prevent the default behavior of form submit.

2) Create a session and use userid in session variable

Comment: @TYAGI.. false prevents the behaviour of form submit, but here both true and false the form is submitting and move to demo_form.html

Answer (score 0):

I did't got exact error but in my case this following code works you can try this also

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()        
     {  
         alert("sdfdfsf");
        // return false;
        var x=document.forms["myForm"]["StuserID"].value;  
            if (x==null || x=="")  
      {  
         alert("Name must be filled out");  
          return false;  
      }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="GET">      
    <input type="text" name="StuserID" id="basic" value=""  placeholder="userID"   /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

and you can use jquery function also

Like [.submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: @manwal.. thank for your reply..the stuf you mentoined above,i alredy done.. If userId is null show an alert and kept in form view.. But here showing the alert  "Name must be filled out".. if we press the ok in alert it moves to  demo_form.html.. i don't want tat..